# How to cluster poorly sampled regions together in space

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, geospatial, hierarchical-clustering

My data set consists of 15000 fish market samples taken at around 150 harbours. Unfortunately, the sampling is not uniformly distributed, and some harbours have 1-10 samples, and others have 1000. I would like to aggregate these harbours together so that I achieve both of the following:

1. harbours that are geographically close to each other get clustered together
2. the final clusters all have roughly similar sampling density e.g. 1000 samples

Item #1 can be done on its own using a standard clustering based on distance. But how can I achieve #2 on top of this..? What tools/methods should I be looking at? (preferably in R)

Comment: A suggestion for #1; group by long:lat coordinates? Without seeing the data, and therefore if it would be applicable, `k-mean` could be used to cluster the harbours. `k-means` uses the  euclidean distance between objects so you would be getting harbours closet to each other grouped.

Comment: I should have been a bit clearer. #1 can be achieved by more or less any given "standard" clustering method based on the distance between harbours e.g. k-means, PAM, hierarchical clustering etc. But in addition I would like to add a constraint that considers the "weight" or "size" of the point as well as the geographic distance i.e. number of samples taken. So I'm essentially looking for an algorithm that can achieve balance both aspects at once...

Answer (score 0):

Clustering algorithms are *built* to find structure in your data.

Any clustering algorithm that would "split" an harbors data, and merge nearby harbors, would have *failed* to detect this structure.

So with clustering, you are picking exactly the *wrong* tool. It would be reasonable to use clustering to split your data if you would not have harbor information at all (but you have this data). Clustering does *not* care about clusters being the same size: it emphasizes structure, not size.

Comment: Ok, that's a fair enough point, but I'm not completely sure I agree - there are plenty of examples of "constrained clustering" out there, and one could imagine for example a hierarchical algorithm with a stopping rule (i.e. don't cluster if n_samples > 1000).

But technicalities aside, if shouldn't be looking for clustering algorithms, where else should I look?

Comment: Constrained clustering etc. attempt to guide the structure discovery by adding side information on what is a desirable property. For your problem, I'd try the straightforward greedy approach, and a standard optimization problem solver.